# How can I combine multiple images into a single GIMP file with the command line?

Tags: command-line, gimp, automation, conversion, image-processing

How can I combine multiple JPEGs into a single, layered XCF via the command line?

Using GIMP's graphical interface I can choose **File ▸ Open as Layers...**, but I don't see an analogous command-line option. I've tried combining the images using ImageMagick but it doesn't recognize XCF as an output format.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use gimp in batch mode. See: http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

You would probably need to learn script-fu...  http://docs.gimp.org/nl/gimp-using-script-fu-tutorial.html